# How do i get the content of the BufferStrategy/its Graphics in Java?

Tags: java, bufferstrategy

is there a way to get the content of the current Buffer im writing to? a sort of a representation of what i've written to its graphics. For example, in the following code, i would like to get a BufferedImage or even an Array that has values that represent what i've written, in this case; a black background and a white rectangle:

```
public static void render (Canvas canvas) {
        BufferStrategy buffer = canvas.getBufferStrategy();
        Graphics g = buffer.getDrawGraphics();
        
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());

        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.drawRect(50, 50, 100, 100);   

        g.dispose();
        // Maybe a method here that allows me to get what has been writen?
        buffer.show();                  
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Generally, no.  If you wanted this kind of feature, then you'd need to make it yourself.  Remember in this case, you're using a "page flipping" process, where there is a "presented" buffer and then a series of "off screen" buffers.  You write to the off screen buffer(s) and then request that it be made the "presentation" buffer

Comment: @MadProgrammer Alright, thank you. I'll post it here if i end up creating it.